# i want to fetch my dropdownlist data i wrote a code but it isn't working

Tags: php

I tried this code to fetch my selected radio element  but the result that i had is:   the  element of the radio that appears is not the selected elements

```php
<div class="panel-body">

   <div class="radio"> 

      <div class="form-group">             
      <label><input type="radio" name="c5" value="a" <?php echo ($row['device_typ'] ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> /> unité centrale  </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">  
      <label><input type="radio" name="c5" value="b" <?php echo ($row['device_typ'] ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>  /> écran  </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">  
      <label><input type="radio" name="c5" value="c" <?php echo ($row['device_typ'] ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>  /> clavier  </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">  
      <label><input type="radio" name="c5" value="d" <?php echo ($row['device_typ'] ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>  /> souris </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <label><input type="radio" name="c5" value="e" <?php echo ($row['device_typ'] ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> /> équipement spéciale </label>

   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to compare your database value against your input radio as below

```
<label><input type="radio" name="c5" value="a" <?php echo ($row['device_typ']=='a') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> /> unité centrale  </label>
```

Comment: Mohsin Marui  i did like you said but any element of the radio box is selected although i have checked in the database that there is a selected item

Comment: in your database storing each radio buttons value like a,b,c,d then you need to compare all radio button's value against the database value

Comment: Mohsin Marui i am working with phpmyadmin  i have created one field named "device_typ" that contain the selected item. how can i store in my db each radio buttons value like a,b,c,d

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing each radio button values, for example

```
$row['device_typ'] = 'a';
```

Your code should be

```
 <div class="panel-body">

   <div class="radio"> 

  <div class="form-group">             
  <label><input type="radio" name="c5" value="a" <?php echo ($row['device_typ'] == 'a') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> /> unité centrale  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">  
  <label><input type="radio" name="c5" value="b" <?php echo ($row['device_typ'] == 'b') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>  /> écran  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">  
  <label><input type="radio" name="c5" value="c" <?php echo ($row['device_typ'] == 'c') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>  /> clavier  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">  
  <label><input type="radio" name="c5" value="d" <?php echo ($row['device_typ'] == 'd') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>  /> souris </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label><input type="radio" name="c5" value="e" <?php echo ($row['device_typ'] == 'e') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> /> équipement spéciale </label>
```

Comment: Rakesh Jakhar i did exactly like that but unlike nothing appears in the radio box i mean any radio is selected although i have checked in the database the there is a selected element

Comment: @Mar please share print_r($row)